# ¿Cómo corregir el error: La instrucción INSERT entró en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY "FK_ContactoPrincipal_LADA"?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

Tengo un problema al querer hacer un INSERT desde mi programa WPF. AL querer insertar mi registro me aparece este error con la siguiente definición...
**'El conflicto ocurrió en la base de datos "Soluciones", tabla "dbc.Table", columna "Columna". La instrucción se ha terminado.'**
Entendiendo que el error esta en mis constraint, porque antes el error me apareció en un constrint CHECK que tuve que eliminar, y ahora el error me aparece en mis constrint FOREIGN KEY

Trate de insertar mis datos con procesadores almacenados. Mi tabla SQLServer esta construida de esta manera..

```
CREATE TABLE ContactoPrincipal(
idContactoPrincipal INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Nombre NVARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
Apellidos NVARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(70) CHECK(Email LIKE '%@%.%') NOT NULL,
Lada VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Telefono VARCHAR(18) CHECK(Telefono LIKE '[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_ContactoPrincipal_Lada FOREIGN KEY (Lada) REFERENCES Ladas(Lada) 
);
```

Mi Procedimiento Almacenado está construido así...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertarContactoPrincipal
@Nombre NVARCHAR(60),
@Apellidos NVARCHAR(60),
@Email VARCHAR(70),
@Lada VARCHAR(10),
@Telefono VARCHAR(18)
AS 
INSERT INTO ContactoPrincipal(Nombre,Apellidos,Email,Lada,Telefono)VALUES(@Nombre,@Apellidos,@Email,@Lada,@Telefono)
GO
```

Dentro de mi programa cree una clase llamada CD_Cliente...

```
public void ContactoPrincipal(string Nombre, string Apellidos, string Email, string Lada, string Telefono)
        {
            comando.Connection = conexion.Connection();
            comando.CommandText = "InsertarContactoPrincipal";
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@Nombre", SqlDbType.NVarChar,60).Value = Nombre;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@Apellidos", SqlDbType.NVarChar,60).Value = Apellidos;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar,60).Value = Email;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@Lada", SqlDbType.VarChar,10).Value = Lada;
            comando.Parameters.Add("@Telefono", SqlDbType.VarChar,18).Value = Telefono;

            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

            comando.Parameters.Clear();
            conexion.CloseConnection();
        }
```

Una segunda clase llamada CN_Cliente...

```
private CD_Cliente clienteCD = new CD_Cliente();
 public void ContactoPrincipal(string Nombre, string Apellidos, string Email, string Lada, string Telefono)
        {
            clienteCD.ContactoPrincipal(Nombre, Apellidos, Email, Lada, Telefono);
        }
```

En un evento Button_Click quiero hacer mi INSERT, así que hice lo siguiente...

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContactoPrincipal cp = new ContactoPrincipal();
            if (Editar == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    clienteCN.ContactoPrincipal(cp.txtnombre.Text, cp.txtapellidos.Text, cp.txtemail.Text, cp.cmbLada.Text, cp.txtnumtelefonico.Text);
                    MessageBox.Show("CONTACTO GUARDADO"); 
                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("NO SE INSERTO CONTACTO: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

No sé si sea necesario eliminar mis restricciones para poder hacer mi inserción desde mi programa. Si todo se puede hacer sin eliminar ninguna restricción, les agradecería demasiado su respuesta

Comment: Y el valor que usas en Lada, ya existe en la tabla Ladas? No? Por qué no existe? (es una pregunta de lógica de negocio, no de la BD). Habría que crearlo primero?

Comment: Mi problema no es eso, porque mi ComboBox se llena con la fila de mi tabla Lada :)

Comment: Cuál combobox? No lo veo 8-) No sabemos si están enviando un valor incorrecto para el campo Lada por un mal armado del combobox. Te toca [edit] y añadir el código correspondiente

Comment: La duda planteada aquí: *"No sé si sea necesario eliminar mis restricciones para poder hacer mi inserción desde mi programa"* es un punto neurálgico que deberías resolver muy seriamente. ¿Necesitas las restricciones? Entonces ponlas y luego escribe el código de modo que se adapte a la realidad de tus datos, no al revés. El problema es que si vas quitando cosas para creer resolver un problema (que el código corra sin errores) más adelante te encontrarás un problema mayor: datos inconsistentes porque quitaste restricciones, programa lento porque quitaste índices o dependencias entre tablas etc

Comment: Tal vez no me estoy explicando bieen. Sí, lo que necesito es adaptar el código, pero no tengo idea de como adaptarlo de acuerdo a mi restricciones, porque es eso lo que me esta causando problemas al hacer mi INSERT.

Comment: Pues te voy a poner un ejemplo: Si tu tabla tiene definida esta restricción: `CONSTRAINT FK_ContactoPrincipal_Lada FOREIGN KEY (Lada) REFERENCES Ladas(Lada)`, lo lógico es que allí donde se introducen los datos para ser insertados, el valor que irá destinado a la columna `Lada` de `ContactoPrincipal` sea tomado de un dropdown que se llena con todas las filas de la tabla `Ladas`, así te aseguras de que nunca se intentará insertar un registro huérfano. Eso no quita que verifiques el código de inserción, emitiendo un mensaje de error al usuario cuando intente insertar registros huérfanos.

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos**

El `CONSTRAINT` (por así decirlo) te indica que dato no existe en la tabla y columna con la cual esta relacionada en este caso su `FK`. En el caso particular con `FK_ContactoPrincipal_Lada` acorde a lo que compartes; implica que el valor que quieres agregar en la tabla **`ContactoPrincipal`** en su campo *`Lada`* no existe en la tabla **`Ladas`** en su campo *`Lada`* (que en esta muy seguro es una `PK` y única).

```
CREATE TABLE ContactoPrincipal(
   idContactoPrincipal INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   Nombre NVARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
   Apellidos NVARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
   Email VARCHAR(70) CHECK(Email LIKE '%@%.%') NOT NULL,
   Lada VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   Telefono VARCHAR(18) CHECK(Telefono LIKE '[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT FK_ContactoPrincipal_Lada FOREIGN KEY (Lada) REFERENCES Ladas(Lada) 
);
```

No modifiques la Base de Datos los `CONSTRAINT` no deben ser eliminados para agregar o modificar registros. Debes revisar la tabla con que está relacionado; ya que con ello se conserva y asegura la integridad de los datos y su relación.

Desde luego que la forma más fácil es eliminar `CONSTRAINT`; más sin embargo cuando quieras (en este caso) sacar una consulta que implique obtener lo que mediante la Lada se relaciona en las tablas respectivas aquellos que no coincidan no tendrás tus datos/consulta completa.

Lo idóneo es que tengas un **List** que te permita seleccionar la `Lada` y tomar lo que corresponda a su PK respectiva para así no tengas obtengas ese error; y así cualquiera donde exista ese tipo de relación.